# Modificar o título de uma aba do navegador com Javascript

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Esconder titulos</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto">
        <button id="btn">Aplicar T�tulo</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Eu tenho uma extensão que recebe um texto e através de um input e gostaria de aplicá-lo na aba aberta do navegador, substituindo o título original.

```js
  

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
        let text = document.querySelector('#texto').value;
    });
});
```

Qual seria o comando para fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia incluir o HTML na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 4):

Use o [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title). Lembrando que vai alterar a tag `title` na DOM também.

```
document.title = "Novo título"
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente dessa maneira:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerText = 'titulo';
```

Answer (score 0):

Para "pegar" o conteudo do input informado vc pode usar:

```
var entrada = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
```

E para atribuir o valor coletado no input ao titulo da pagina vc pode usar:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML=entrada;
```

Atribuindo uma ID("#btn") no elemento botão do HTML vc pode ter o javascript abaixo:

```
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var entrada = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML=entrada;      
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma variável para armazenar o input, depois coloque está variável como valor da tag "title"

```
var input = document.getElementById("texto").value;

document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = input;
/*Peguei a tag "title" e coloquei como "innerHTML" a variável input
onde foi armazenado o valor do input*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Para manipular o ttulo de uma página você utilizar a propriedade `document.title`. Para você modificar só precisa atribuir um novo valor a esta propriedade da seguinte maneira:
`document.title = text;`

Código com solução.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
        let text = document.querySelector('#texto').value;
        document.title = text;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Minha solução para esse problema é um pouco diferente.

No HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="texto" id="texto">
<button onclick="altTitle()">botãotitle</button>
```

Já no arquivo script.js:

```
function altTitle(){
    input = document.getElementById("texto").value;
    document.title = input; 
};
```